# When 'is_post_type_archive()' return true?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, archives

I visit archive page link

*http://src.wordpress-develop.dev/2016/*

or

*http://src.wordpress-develop.dev/category/Markup/*,

on either page `is_post_type_archive()` return `false`.

I have added `is_post_type_archive()` in `archive.php` template file.

I have tried putting `is_post_type_archive()` in and out the loop,
 use `wp_reset_query()` before the `is_post_type_archive()`, but all return `false`.

How can I make `is_post_type_archive()` function return `true`?

Comment: Run it on a custom post type archive page

Answer (score 4):

> When 'is_post_type_archive()' return true?

[`is_post_type_archive()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_post_type_archive/) returns true for **`custom post type archives`** and false for default posts.

Use [`is_archive()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_archive/) to check for default posts.

Answer (score 0):

http://src.wordpress-develop.dev/category/Markup/ 
 or another link is not a **post type archive page**, it is a **archive page**. **archive page** is not a **post type archive page**. **archive page** access link like above, but **post type archive page** access link like:
http://src.wordpress-develop.dev/(post-type)

replace the (post-type) with the really post type.

There is no **post type archive pages** for the build in post types, only for **custom post types** when `has_archive` is set(I can't prove that). So only when you create a **custom post type** like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'acme_product',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Products' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
}
```

then you can access your **custom post type archive page** through link **website-url/acme-product**, the template file **archive-{post_type}.php** or **archive.php** either used. In the context, either in **archive-{post_type}.php** or **archive.php** the `is_post_type_archive()` function return true, otherwise always return false.

`is_post_type_archive (string|array $post_types = '' )`

Is the query for existing post type archive page?